# Using KeyboardEvent to simulate a keypress for a test

Tags: javascript, keyboard, automated-tests, dom-events

I want to write a Javascript test that simulates a keypress on the right arrow key.  Here is my attempt to create the `keydown` event:

```
var data = {
   key: 'ArrowRight'
};
var ev = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', data);
console.log(ev);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lsiden/6e7duck6/

When I examine the output in the developer console, I expect to see the value 39 in one of the event fields, but it appears to remain uninitialized.

```
KeyboardEvent {which: 0, keyCode: 0, charCode: 0, repeat: false, metaKey: false…}
altKey: false
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
charCode: 0
ctrlKey: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
detail: 0
eventPhase: 0
keyCode: 0
keyIdentifier: ""
keyLocation: 0
layerX: 0
layerY: 0
location: 0
metaKey: false
pageX: 0
pageY: 0
path: Array[0]
repeat: false
returnValue: true
shiftKey: false
srcElement: null
target: null
timeStamp: 1430931169397
type: "keydown"
view: null
which: 0
__proto__: KeyboardEvent
.
```

I tried to follow the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Did you use chrome browser or firefox browser to test this?

Comment: It's been a while, but it was probably Chrome.

Comment: Ok then. The chrome is the reason for that. I have found solution that will work with chrome also. Did you find the workaround for this problem? I know it has past more then 5 months.

Comment: Sorry, it's been too long.

Comment: Not a problem. I think i have solution. I will post it so that other will have easy life.

Answer (score 1):

I won't lie, this seems odd to test. It sounds like you need to wrap all the functionality of that key press event into one function and then test that function.

If you did that already and you need to test that your function is looking for a certain keyCode or something, then you can use plain javascript objects and pass that into the function you're testing.

e.g.

if your function looks like this.

```
function myFunc(evt) {
  if (evt.keyCode === 39) {
    doThis();
  } else {
    doThat();
  }
}
```

Then to test your function, all you need is an object with a keyCode equal to 39. Your function shouldn't care about the fact that it was triggered with a KeyBoardEvent object that has a bunch of other stuff attached to it that you don't need.

So your test will look like this.

```
var keyboardEvent = {keyCode: 39};
myFunc(keyboardEvent);
// Make sure that doThis() was called and not doThat()
```

I think that would solve your problem and make things simpler.

Comment: My goal was to test that a web component will receive a a real keyboard event as generated by the browser, not just that it can process it correctly.  Nevertheless, your suggestion implies that I could break this into two tests, which will be useful to remember if faced with this situation again.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and realized that it works in Firefox, but not Chrome. Chrome doesnt seem to use 'key' attribute in the KeyboardEvent. You have to use 'keyIdentifier'. To test in both browsers, you can do this:

```
var data = {
       key: 'ArrowRight',
       keyIdentifier:'ArrowRight'
    };
var ev = new KeyboardEvent('keydown', data);
console.log(ev);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I'm facing another issue
`TS2345: Argument of type '{ key: string; keyIdentifier: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'KeyboardEventInit'`
Do you have an idea on how to resolve it? Thx